# What will happen when my laptop with a broken battery that is connected to a charger thinks battery goes to zero?

Tags: laptop, battery

I have an old HP ENVY TouchSmart 4-1103eo laptop with Ubuntu installed on it. While it still was running Windows, it used to turn off when it said it had about 40 % of battery remaining. Then its battery broke completely and was replaced. Some day its Windows installation also somehow broke and it could only run the file recovery app, nothing else. After that I installed Ubuntu on it and it has worked fine, though its battery is (once again) broken.

It hasn't been used without a charger for a long time, but yet on the top right it says a percentage that is supposed to tell how much battery is remaining. For fairly long this number was 94% and it sometimes agreed to charge up to 100 %. Then on one boot it was 43%, then 35 % for a couple of boots and now it's 21 % [EDIT: 20 % while adding release information below]. So far, this has affected nothing but the percentage shown on screen.

Since that number is now going down, I'm worried what will happen when that goes to zero. With this trend it's probably not many boots away. At that time, will my computer think "oh, I have no battery remaining, I'm not going to start up at all despite being connected to a charger"?

I'm not planning to use this computer any longer on battery as I only use it for some specific purposes.

I just installed acpi, and it says the following:

```
Battery 0: Discharging, 0%, rate information unavailable
Battery 1: Unknown, 21%
```

What does that tell you? Do I need to bring this computer to a repair shop and ask for the battery to be removed? When the battery was replaced, I could use this computer without a battery. Back then it was still running Windows and hovering the cursor on the battery icon brought up the text "Battery has not been found" (or rather the same in Finnish, "Akkua ei ole löydetty").

EDIT: Release information:

```
<USERNAME>@EnvyLinux:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: Which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Now the battery has gone to zero, and the computer seems to work still just fine. The icon on the top right shows a battery with a lightning inside, no percentage as it used to, but `acpi` prints the following:

```
Battery 0: Discharging, 0%, rate information unavailable
Battery 1: Unknown, 0%
```

Next to the charger slot, this laptop model has a light that is supposed to be orange when charging and white when battery is full and the computer is connected to a charger (I can't remember what color it was when not connected to the battery, I guess it was orange as well). On the last boot before zero the percentage was 9 %, but the light switched from white to orange to white again indefinitely, changing color about every half a second. After this one "special" boot, the battery went to zero and the light is white.